# "Unexpected end of file" error in perfectly error-free PHP file with custom router.php

Tags: php, syntax, syntax-error

Currently I am using PHP's built in web server, and I recently started using a custom router script so that I can effectively implement a custom 404 page. Here is router.php:

```
<?php
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir($root);
$path = '/'.ltrim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'],'/');
set_include_path(get_include_path().':'.__DIR__);
if(file_exists($root.$path))
{
    if(is_dir($root.$path) && substr($path,strlen($path) - 1, 1) !== '/')
        $path = rtrim($path,'/').'/index.php';
    if(strpos($path,'.php') === false) return false;
    else {
        chdir(dirname($root.$path));
        require_once $root.$path;
    }
}else include_once 'pages/404.php';
```

However, I have a login page that uses PHP to... login, of course. However, using this router.php, the login page gives me the usual "[website] cannot handle your request" and the logs say `Unexpected end of file`. The code worked just fine until now (and passes many syntax checkers), so I suspect either my router.php somehow isn't fit to run proper PHP files, or it's messing with how said files are handled. 
Heres my login PHP:

```
<?php
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$return = $_GET['return'];
if (!isset($_GET['return']))
{
    echo "<span>No return page is selected to return to, please go back to the <a href='../'>Home page</a> and go to a different page.</span>";
}
if($user == "adminuser"
&& $pass == "adminpass")
{
        include("../pages/" . $return . "/secret/secure.php");
}
else
{
    if(isset($_POST))
    {?>
            <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Login V6</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.ico"/>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/iconic/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
<!--===============================================================================================-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100">
            <div class="wrap-login100 p-t-85 p-b-20">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="index.php?monster=<?php echo $monster ?>">
                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-70">
                        Welcome
                    </span>
                    <span class="login100-form-avatar">
                        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="AVATAR">
                    </span>
                    <input type="hidden" name="monster" value="<?php $_GET['monster'];?>">

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-t-85 m-b-35" data-validate = "Enter username">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Username"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input m-b-50" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Password"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <input class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></input>
                    </div>

                    <ul class="login-more p-t-190">
                        <li class="m-b-8">
                            <span class="txt1">
                                Forgot
                            </span>

                            <a href="../index.html#contact" class="txt2">
                                Username / Password?
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="dropDownSelect1"></div>

<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/animsition/js/animsition.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/popper.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/select2/select2.min.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="vendor/countdowntime/countdowntime.js"></script>
<!--===============================================================================================-->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
    <?}
}
?>
```

I know next to nothing about the science behind PHP routers (and I got mine from a stackoverflow answer), so if something in my router.php is painfully wrong, well, that's why :/

Comment: *“Unexpected end of file” error in perfectly error-free PHP file* ... if it was perfectly error free, you wouldn't be getting an error -_-

Comment: Copying something without understanding what it does is a quick route to getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `php` to `<?` in Your login.php:
    `</body>
    </html>
    <?}<- this one
    }
    ?>`

Comment: Removed it, got the same error. Like I said the login page has passed many syntax checks and was working before.

Comment: @ElijahBansley - he's not saying remove it, but change `<?` to `<?php`

Comment: @CD001 Yes, but I've edited my answer - he could saw old version.

Comment: @bigwolk - oki, maybe the poke I gave him then will make him see the updated version ;)

Comment: @CD001 I hope so :), but I'm not sure if he don't get a message about answer edit in his question  - is there something like that?

Comment: When you '@' someone (as I did in my first comment) it automatically pings their message box, the same as you get when I comment on your answer - so he'd have had a notification from my first comment if nothing else.

Comment: I was busy, sorry heheh. I tried that too, same error. (I have already tried that but I tried again just now to be sure)

Comment: @ElijahBarnsley I would suggest cut&run method to check where is a problem - just cut out everything, then paste part of code - if it wil run successfully, paste another part of code and run it. Of course You need to paste syntax correctly parts of code - if You paste starting `if() {` expression paste ending bracket too.

Comment: I guess ill give it a shot.

Comment: ok forgive me, for this is gonna sound really stupid... but you were right  lol. its the <?php, but I SWEAR I tried that TWICE and it didnt work. I also tried reformatting the HTML inside the ?><?php as well, which probably is what did it. I guess problem solved?

Comment: Maybe You've got some cache which stores Yours problem, but anyway - It will be solved when You say it is :) I'm glad I could help.